# Trying to open a file in netrw sometimes opens the wrong file

Tags: vim, neovim, netrw

I'm using netrw in my NeoVim setup to navigate files. I typically open netrw with `:Explore` which I've mapped to `<c-e>` and open files / expand directories by pressing enter with my cursor on the target. About 50% of the time however, pressing enter will instead open whatever file is at the bottom of the netrw window, very frustrating. Has anyone else experienced this? The only mapping I have for `<cr>` while a netrw buffer is active is:

```
n  <CR>         @<Plug>NetrwLocalBrowseCheck
```

which I think is standard netrw stuff?

Comment: I have the same problem! I also sometimes try to open a file and find that instead, the filename with the last 2 characters removed is opened (a new buffer).

Quite probably this mistake is in one of the plugins that we both have installed. Can I have a look at your list? [My plugins are here.](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/vimrc/blob/master/plugins.vim)

Comment: oo can't access that page. i've actually since switched to using [vim-dirvish](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish) and haven't looked back since, would thoroughly recommend

Comment: fwiw the plugins i use are listed [here](https://github.com/dbatten5/dotfiles/blob/main/nvim/plugins.vim#L9) @TamaMcGlinn

Comment: I tried removing our common 5 plugins, and just now got the problem again. So my suspicion is false. This is quite possibly a bug in neovim. I see you raised it there: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/13215